# Creación de proyecto FIREBASE 3 + ionic1

Tags: angularjs, ionic, firebase

Hola soy nuevo con firebase, este ultimo tiempo de estudio me he encontrado varas formas de crear las conexiones pero ninguna me sale, aparentemente la version 3 de firebase es distinta.

Ahora sera posible ayudarme a armar mi proyecto y así poder entender bien su nueva estructura? a final quedara para todos esto, Gracias.

En primera instancia yo agregue 2 librerias al **HTML**:

```
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.0/firebase.js"</script>
```

```
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/2.0.2/angularfire.min.js </script>
```

Luego me voy **app.js** a configurar lo siguiente:

Primero:

```
var app = angular.module('starter', [

    'ionic',
    'starter.controllers',
    'starter.services',
    'firebase'
]);
```

Luego:

```
 var config = {

  apiKey: "AIzaSyCkqKaKJhgJHJJRckoP8haIp2iwA2OyekMqeULo",

authDomain: "casaco-60018.firebaseapp.com",

databaseURL: "https://casaco-60018.firebaseio.com",

 storageBucket: "casaco-60018.appspot.com",

 messagingSenderId: "103998557190"

};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
```

> Este ultimo no tengo claro si debe de ir acá o en el controlador!

Y por ultimo **Controlador** ¿si yo quisiera hacer un login con facebook esta correcto esto?

```
    controller('login',function(que importo?){

  var auth = firebase.auth();

  var provider = new firebase.auth.facebookAuthProvider();
  auth.signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
    // User signed in!
    var uid = result.user.uid;
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // An error occurred
  });

});
```

¿Como seria la forma de hacer un crud en el controller?

```
    Controller('crud',function(){


   });
```

Por favor armemos este proyecto yo lo ire editando... y al final quedara para todos y me ayudara a mí, podria despues hacer un commit y subirlo a git y así lo puedan bajar, lo comento todo.

Saludos,

Comment: Creo que tienes demasiadas dudas a la vez. Deberías escoger algo más concreto para poder responderte.

Comment: como creo el codigo para conectar al login en facebook. tengo todo configurado pero no me quiere salir.